# Error running SQL in MS-Access with ODBC connection to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, driver

I was helping a non-profit migrate MS-Access data to MYSQL. So, I ported data to MYSQL and created links in ms-access to MYSQL tables using ODBC. Majority of the existing SQL works fine. However I am stumped on this one error -

You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near UNION...

I have stripped the SQL with 7 UNIONS to bare bones where it still fails.

```
(SELECT 1 as A FROM Households H)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2 as A FROM Households H)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 3 as A FROM Households H)
```

The part that is getting to me is that I am able to run above successfully as long as I run only one UNION meaning below SQL, but the moment I add a third one, it gives ODBC error

```
(SELECT 1 as A FROM Households H)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2 as A FROM Households H)
```

I tried using **`** or **'** or **[]** but none of these helped. The reason I am frustrated with this error is that either it should fail with all or none, it gives an error only when using two or more UNION clauses. Could this be a potential bug in driver?

I am using mysql-64 bit on win-7 64bit with ms-access and a 32-bit driver. It shouldn't be an architecture problem as I am able to run other queries with multiple UNIONs, and accessing the same set of tables.

It would be great if someone can give pointers on how to debug this further.

Comment: Does the (original) query run from a regular (non-ODBC) MySQL client?

Comment: Does wrapping `select * (...) as foo` around it help?  Note: The A,B,C weirds me out because it doesn't do anything useful...

Comment: Original SQL runs fine from MS-Access front-end accessing ms-access back-end. There is a Dateadd function in the original SQL, so I ported that to MYSQL and was able to run the query in MYSQL directly. The problem is that I cannot use mysql syntax for a query coded in ms-access, so I have to use the original query as it is.

Comment: I had tried selecing HouseholdID, which is PK in Households, and still got the same error.

Comment: With regular non-odbc client I meant command-line mysql tool, HeidiSQL or something similar. I'm pretty sure Microsoft Access connects through ODBC.

Comment: Yup, the SQL I pasted here runs fine on mysql client. The original SQL had a dateadd function, so I even ported that to mysql syntax and was able to run it.

Comment: Okay, so Access chokes on `select * (...) as foo` with "Syntax error in JOIN operation." which doesn't seem quite right either...

Comment: Do you have `ORDER BY` clauses in the subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my version of Access, when I edit a query in Design (SQL) view there are three buttons at the top.  "Union", "Pass-Through", and "Data Definition".

If I click "Pass-Through" your query works.  If I click "Union" it breaks.  Can you get away with using "Pass-Through" for this query?

Even in "Union" or "Data Definition" mode, this seems to work:

```
(SELECT 1, column1 as A FROM Households H)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2, column2 as A FROM Households H)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 3, column3 as A FROM Households H);
```

Maybe Access is confused by only a single column?

Alternatively, just use a a multiplex table instead of a union:

```
SELECT mux.id,
IIf(mux.id=1,column1,IIf(mux.id=2,column2,column3)) AS A
FROM Households, mux;
```

Note: mux table should have 3 values in it 1,2,3.  If it has more, you'd want to limit to the first 3 (or n) in a where clause.

Comment: I don't remember correctly what happened when I changed UNION to Pass-thru. I'll give this a shot tonight, and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I read a little more about Pass-through. It means that SQL would be executed on the Server(mysql in this case) directly instead of the linked tables on MS-Access. So, I ported the query into mysql syntax and it worked perfectly! Thanks, your inputs got me going!

Comment: I think that UNION-type(ms-access option, not SQL UNION) gives an error because it runs SQL on access itself, so somehow the SQL is not being translated correctly through the driver to mysql format.

Comment: Official definition from MS - 
***Union** :An SQL specific select query that combines corresponding fields from two or more tables or queries into one field

**Pass-Through**:An SQL specific query that sends commands directly to an SQL database server (such as Microsoft SQL Server). With pass-through queries, you work with the tables on the server instead of linking the tables to your Microsoft Access database.

**Data Definition** :An SQL specific query that can create or delete an index, or create, alter, or delete a table

Answer (score 1):

It is a known MySQL problem: [more than two UNION SELECT statement problem (with MS Access)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7684)  but I don't know if the problem is in the MSAccess SQL parser (which compiles to ODBC SQL), or in the MySQL ODBC driver (which compiles ODBC SQL to MySQL SQL)

To work it out, I'd have to look at the ODBC log, and the ODBC specification, and see if Access was emmitting valid ODBC SQL.

That would be a waste of effort, since it makes more sense to use a pass-through query anyway. The main reason for using a native MSAccess query in this place would be to join to different data sources - for example, an Excel Spreadsheet and a MySQL table -, and according to the comments on the MySQL bug report, the problem goes away when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about where the problem lies, but I think (though it's only an assumption) that this is on MS Access side. I had two `UNION` queries, each of them was putting some other queries together. Both used somewhat complicated sub-queries so I had lots of problem to create a pass-through query and I didn't want to use MySQL "views".

Surprisingly one of my queries worked, the other showed an error. My idea is that the working query used some Access features while the other was some kind of `SELECT ... FROM`'s .

I don't know the rules but I think that when your query is simple, Access sends it to external database engine and puts one more bracket and causes an error. If you do a comlicated query, Access gets all data it needs and makes all necessary operations itself. For example, you may try to create a pivot query, that uses MSSQL `TRANSFORM` statement, which does not exist in MySQL, so it is obvious that Access handles it itself. So why couldn't it make `SELECT` by itself? I don't know. Maybe some performance reasons?

My working query differed from the other that it had one more (string) field that was calculated by built-in Access function. It used also Access `&` operator, which has another meaning (logical AND) in MySQL. (By the way to join strings in MySQL use `CONCAT` function). They of course need to be evaluated by Access, because MySQL does not understand this method of joining strings together.

I suggest just to make `UNION` not from tables, but from queries (like `SELECT * FROM tablename` and nothing more) and giving them a field that you don't need but that will force Access to handle the query. So a query (in Access) should look like this:

```
SELECT tablename.*, [somefield1]&[somefield2] AS useless_field FROM tablename;
```

(in my Access 2000 operations like `"a" & "b"` or `IIf(true;true;false)` were probably simplified and solved, so it didn't work. I think one needs at least one dynamic field to evaluate. I also did no performance tests. Probably it would be fastest if you add to integers, maybe just increase your index by 1?).

Then, of course, you join it together:

```
SELECT * FROM query1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM query2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM query3
UNION ALL
```

...

```
SELECT * FROM queryn
;
```

You don't need this `useless_field` of course.

I agree that this is a workaround but I have no other ideas.